# Adding Tinymce editor in nestedfields in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

In my rails application I have used nested forms to add more div and inside each div which is created dynamically using nested forms I need to use Tinymce editor to edit it's logo name..The problem is Tinymce editor is not loaded correctly inside div. When I press button once it loads but when I press it again and again only the tool bar appear but not the text area. Please anyone help me solve this problem.

```
 $(function () {
       if (typeof tinyMCE != 'undefined') {
           tinyMCE.init({
               selector: "textarea.tinymce",
               toolbar: "styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify",
                   "bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | code | codesample"
               ],
               plugins: "image,link,code,codesample,autoresize,imagetools,media,table,insertdatetime,charmap,print,preview,anchor,searchreplace,visualblocks,fullscreen"
           });
       } else {
           setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50);
       }
   });
```

my html code where i inserted editor;

```
 <div class="ckedit1">
   <button type="button" id="button-name2">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
   </button>
 </div>
 <div class="editor-carousel">
    <%= text_area :carousel, "", :class => "tinymce", :rows => 3, :cols => 20 %>
    <button type="button" id="button-carousel2">ok</button>
 </div>
<%= tinymce %>
```

Jquery to toggle editor;

```
$(function() {
  $("#button-name2").click(function(event) {
    console.log("button-name");
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".editor-carousel").toggle();
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#button-carousel2").click(function(event) {
    console.log("button-carousel");
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".editor-carousel").toggle();
  });
});
```

[My view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1vsh.png)

Comment: Your html is bad formatted and you have a typo around `toolbar`. You can start here.

Comment: Can u explain more?